# select all rows with same column name in dataframe

Tags: r

I've a dataframe with repetition in colnames.

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0))
df<-rbind(df,c(1:8))
colnames(df) <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c1","c2","c5","c6")

> df
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c1 c2 c5 c6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

As visible, column `c1` and `c2` repeat two times. But i can access only first occurring column on call to dataframe.

```
> df$c1
[1] 1
> df$c2
[1] 2
> df[,"c1"]
[1] 1
> df[,"c2"]
[1] 2
```

How can i access all values ie. `c1: 1, c1:5` on calling some sort of `df[,"c1"]` ?

> Note: The reason behind dataframe having repeated colnames is due to conversion of nested list into dataframe

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you won't want to change the column names? If not, that's probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Maybe you need to use the index positions of the column then. `df[1]` and `df[5]`.

Comment: `df[names(df) %in% 'c1']`

Comment: @Z.Lin, the reason behind that it is dynamic, actual data contains `vision-api result` with property `categories.detail.celebrities.name`. For every different image passed, it generates different _number of celebrity_ names (null or 3-4 etc). I am passing multiple images and collecting result for all.

Comment: @RonakShah, that would be too easy...i want to access by colname rather than index

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, i was working the round way. Solution works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want c1 columns try this

```
df[1,names(df) %in% ('c1')]
```

if you want the values of all the columns with duplicated names then try this

```
df[1,names(df) %in% names(df)[duplicated(names(df))]]
```

Comment: I was just going to post this. `df[duplicated(names(df)) |  duplicated(names(df), fromLast = TRUE)]`

Comment: this solution is kinda exactly solving my purpose, Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0));
df <- rbind(df, c(1:8));
colnames(df) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c1", "c2", "c5", "c6");
df[, names(df) == 'c1'];
sapply(unique(names(df)), function(x) unname(unlist(df[, names(df) == x])))
```